# Premiere Pro - How to paste effects? (namely opacity)

Tags: premiere

I am familiar with the `copy` and `paste attributes` method for pasting effects on multiple clips, however when I tried this method to paste my opacity keyframes from one clip to another, nothing happened.

All I'm after is some animated opacity levels (start from 50% reach 100% opacity in the middle of the clip then at the end of the clip bring the opacity down to 0%).

### Question

Does `paste-attributes` not work for opacity? If not, what is a similar labor-saving solution I can try?

Comment: The method you describe should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to copy opacity effect with keyframes, you should select keyframes and press CTRL+C, then select clip on timeline and move playhead to time where you want to put first keyframe, then select effect controls window and click CTRL+V to paste. That's all.

In such way you can copy keyframes from one clip to another.

If you want to copy keyframes from one clip to a lot of other clips, you can create preset in such way: